# PostgreSql Search query based on array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one column in a table in which I am querying with the following parameters:

Table:

```
Id    Billno. text[]
---------------------
 1      4545
 2      4545, 4546
```

When I query for `4545`, it must return both rows.

I am using following query but it returns only one row i.e. 4545

```
pool.query(' SELECT "Billno" FROM "table" '+
' where "Billno" @> $1 ',[billNo])
```

Where `billNo = [4545, 3456]` -> It can be any array. But if any number is available in database, it must return it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try explicitly casting your parameter as an ARRAY data type:

```
pool.query(' SELECT "Billno" FROM "table" '+
' where "Billno" @> ARRAY[$1] ',[billNo])
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/701f7/4

Also, is the `Billno` field an array of strings?  If you are storing numeric values, why not use an array of integers?

**Update**
If you want to return all arrays that contain ANY value in your parameterized array value, then try the overlap (&&) operator:

```
pool.query(' SELECT "Billno" FROM "table" '+
' where "Billno" && ARRAY[$1] ',[billNo])
```

Comment: But if we put SELECT Billno FROM mytable 
 where Billno @> ARRAY['4545','4546'] then It  returns only one row.

Comment: Right, it should return only the row with a Billno array that "contains" all the items in the ['4545','4546'] array.

Comment: Are you trying to just return all rows that contain any value within the ['4545','4546'] array?  i.e. return all rows with an array that has either 4545 or 4546?  If so, then try the "overlap" array operator: && (see updated answer above).  The answer above uses the "contains" operator.  See here for more info: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-array.html

Comment: Can we do it for dates as well. I have a date range let say 03-05-2017 to 06-05-2017. I am using "billDate" between $1 and $2, [date, dateto] . How can I get ANY date ?

Comment: If billDate is just a single DATE value, you can use that exact syntax you wrote: `WHERE billDate BETWEEN <date> AND <dateto>`.  That will return rows with any billDate value within the range.  If billDate is an array of DATE values, then you just use the same overlap array operator (&&) as before.

Comment: Can you please provide me that query  (' SELECT  "BillDate" FROM "table" '+
' where "BillDate" between $1 and $2 ',[datefrom,dateto]) ; var datefrom =  ['03-01-2018'];
var dateto = ['05-01-2018'];

Comment: You have it already: `SELECT BillDate FROM table WHERE BillDate BETWEEN <datefrom> AND <dateto>`.  That will give you all rows that have a `BillDate` between the two dates you provided.